# colorPrimary overriding buttonStyle

Tags: java, android-studio

I am currently trying to change the button background of a TicTacToe game. However, the colorPrimary seems to override the buttonStyle because the buttons just stay purple. Removing the colorPrimary attribute just creates a black matrix.

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Tictactoe" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@drawable/ic_button_background</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

ic_button_background:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#0AD6C0"
        android:endColor="#027364"
        android:angle="180" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <stroke android:width="10px" android:color="#D81A60" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton in your XML layout.